# Highlight rough mistakes in JavaScript files in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to get syntax highlighting for rough mistakes in JavaScript in Visual Studio Code?

By rough mistakes I mean things like an attempt to use a variable which doesn't exist.

Comment: Yeah, it's called [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/).

Comment: You could add the ESLint Extension: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try adding this comment at the start of your js file:

```javascript
// @ts-check
```

Comment: Hm, it's cool. But anyway - it's JS-file, not TS. Too many errors in this case))

Comment: I want just to catch rough JS mistakes

Comment: Then configure some linter. [ESLint no-undef](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-undef). Everyone has different 'rough' mistakes

Comment: Ok, some Linter is a way to go